# Responsive slide out menu wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, responsive-design

I used this tutorial to build a responsive slide out menu in a custom wordpress theme: http://sridharkatakam.com/adding-responsive-side-menu-genesis/

I'm having trouble to display the menu button on mobilephones because I can either display the entire menu or no menu.

I'm guessing it has to do with this step from the tutorial:

```
//* Wrap .nav-primary in a #primary-nav-container div
remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_subnav' );
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_subnav', 11 );

add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'sk_add_opening_div', 9 );
function sk_add_opening_div() {
echo '<div id="primary-nav-container">';
}
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'sk_add_closing_div' );
function sk_add_closing_div() { 
echo '</div>';
}

//* Add hamburger font icon below Primary nav
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'sk_hamburger_menu' );
function sk_hamburger_menu() {

echo '<div id="primary-nav-link-container"><div class="wrap"><a id="primary-nav-link"               href="#primary-nav-container"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</a></div></div>';

}
```

Because I'm using a custom theme I cannot use the Genesis hooks to do the code above, so this is my code to display the menu (from header.php):

```
<div id="primary-nav-link-container">
            <div class="wrap">
                <a id="primary-nav-link" href="#primary-nav-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</a>
                    <div class="nav-primary">
                    <div id="primary-nav-container">
                        <divid="menu">                  
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can display the responsive menu only on mobile using CSS media queries? I'm using the code below but this only results in that the desktop version of the menu does not show at all.

The CSS:

```
#primary-nav-link-container {
text-align: center;
display: none;
}

a#primary-nav-link:focus {
outline: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {

#primary-nav-container {
display: none;
}

#primary-nav-link-container {
display: block;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem later I figuerd this out by marking my header like so:

```
<div class="headerarea">

            <div id="primary-nav-link-container">
                <a id="primary-nav-link" href="#primary-nav-container"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</a>                     
                    <div id="primary-nav-container">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>  
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>                         
                    </div>
            </div>          

                    <div id="menu">                 
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
                    </div>              


            </div>
```

and tweaking the css accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

please check the below post.
[Responsive Nav](http://www.phpczar.com/integrate-responsive-nav-js-wordpress-navigation/)

all about for nav menu is mentioned in this post.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, but that is not quite what I'm looking for. The jQuery code that I'm using also has swipe support and it works great, I'm just having problems to hide/show on smaller screens :)